# Как связаться с вебсокетом по аналогии с js android?

Tags: javascript, android, websocket, okhttp

Есть код на js:

```
token = 'some_data';
sid = 'some_data';
ws = new WebSocket('some_data' + sid + '/');
ws.onmessage = function(resp){console.log(resp)};
ws.send(JSON.stringify({'token':token}));
ws.send(JSON.stringify({'chat':{'a':'init', 'rtc_supported': false}}));
ws.send(JSON.stringify({'chat':{'a':'send', 'to': '03654ps', 'body':'preved', 'stamp': 0}}));
```

я пытаюсь сделать подключение к серверу через okHttp:

```
val loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)


val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()

val json = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull()
val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
params["token"] = getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!
val parameter = JSONObject(params as Map<*, *>)

val body: RequestBody = parameter.toString().toRequestBody(json)

val request = Request.Builder()
    .url(CHAT_URL)
    .post(body)
    .build()


val webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, EchoWebSocketListener())

client.dispatcher.executorService.shutdown()
```

если я правильно понял то без токена у меня сервер ничего не вернет. Добавляю токен как можно понять из кода в тело запроса:

```
val json = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull()
val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
params["token"] = getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!
val parameter = JSONObject(params as Map<*, *>)

val body: RequestBody = parameter.toString().toRequestBody(json)
```

Но если делать таким образом, то получаю такую ошибку:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request must be GET: POST
```

Либо эти вещи вообще не так делаются, либо я что-то не так делаю вообще. Сам адрес сервера выглядит так:

```
wss://test_server.net:4433/ws/jwt/jfagdod
```

Не могу понять где именно ошибся и как исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
// тут инициализация client'а
// ...
val request = Request.Builder().url(CHAT_URL).build()
val webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, EchoWebSocketListener())
webSocket.send("{'token':'some token'}")
webSocket.send("{'chat':{'a':'init', 'rtc_supported': false}}");
webSocket.send("{'chat':{'a':'send', 'to': '03654ps', 'body':'preved', 'stamp': 0}}");
// ...
// потом закрыть
webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null); // NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000 rfc6455
```

Вы создаете вебсокет. Соединение устанавливается и не рвется пока кто-то его не порвет, вы или сервер, с ошибкой или нормально. Шлете plaintext в него пока не надоест. Из него соответственно получаете данные тоже plaintext'ом в соответствующем колбэке, если сервер разговорчивый.

Comment: я вот попробовал все как вы и сказали, но не получается :( в логах видно что запрос полетел, а через некоторое время приходит ошибка:
`<-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to test-server.net/ip (port 4433) from /ip (port 42292) after 60000ms` хотя я послал токен как вы и показали

Comment: До токена дело не дошло в таком случае. Коннекта нет. Что-то с сетью/сервером. Браузер с девайса подключается, если страницу с jsкодом запустить?

Comment: сервер вроде нормально работает, насколько я понял)) а как страницу с кодом js запустить?

Comment: Ну у вас откуда-то взялся jsкод, значит он написан и выполняется на какой-то странице. Откройте эту страницу в хроме, в вебвью, где угодно на девайсе. Может быть дело в опечатке просто...

Comment: я то страницу могу открыть с чатом, но я не знаю куда смотреть :( я перешел в логи веб страницы, но там как-то не очень понимаю куда смотреть